# PHP Can't Access Member Of Class (Laravel Illuminate\Http\Request )

Tags: php, laravel

This code:

`dd(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());`

Results in this output:

[image: dump and die log]

How do I get the `baseUrl` that says `/me` instead of the `baseUrl` that says `null`.

If I do `Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()->baseUrl` or variations thereof I always get the null value. I want the not null value (`/me`).

Also looking for an explanation of why there are two properties with the same name on here, one protected and one (I think) not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the getter for the class:

```
(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture())->getBaseUrl();
```